# @Singleton class do I have to make constructor private

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, pmd

I'm writing a Singleton class in Java EE 6 using the @Singleton annotation. I have not declared a constructor.

Do I have to create a private constructor explicitly?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm using PMD and the rule [UseSingleton](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html#UseSingleton)
is flagged. I think that PMD does not understand the annotation @Singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PMD is recommending making the constructor `private` so that others may not instantiate your singleton object.  It's unaware of Java EE 6 annotations.

You can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: When I made my constructor private I had problem during loading of the class at run time, so ha to remove the constructor, is there a way to tell to PMD to suppress warnings, I put @SuppressWarnings("PMD") also tried  to use @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UseSingletone") but it did not pick it up, some warnings seams can not be suppressed.

Comment: For J2EE you'll need to keep the constructor public so that it can be invoked via reflection.  I'm not sure how you suppress warnings with PMD :(

Answer (score 0):

No.  Just add @Singleton on the bean class.

```
@Singleton
public class TesterBean {
  private int testCount = 0;
    public int getCount() {
      return testCount++;
    }
}
```